# bootstrap 3 zoomed out in firefox

Tags: css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser

I've designed a bootstrap 3 site and had tested it exclusively with chrome v40.
I then opened the site with Firefox 36. The layout was zoomed out and had gone all awry but after reducing the zoom to 80% it looked just like it did on chrome.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your index

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```